# What is the complexity of initializing a sorted linked list with n elements?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity

Let's say I have `n` elements that I want to create a sorted linked list with.  Adding the first element is just `O(1)` since the list is initially empty.  Then to add the second element, I have to compare with the first but it should still be constant.  However, as more elements get added, I'm confused as to how to analyze this.  Eventually the worst case scenario for adding an element is going to reach `n` since we are going to have to iterate through all the values on the linked list.  And there are going to be `n` insertions.  So would it end up being   `O(1+2+3+...+n) = O(n)`?

Comment: O(1+2+3+...+n) = O(n) <-- this is wrong. it is actually O(n^2)
sum of a series is (1+n)*n/2 which is order of n squared.

Comment: @TomElias Thank you so much, the answer was staring me right in the face and I messed it up.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Worst Case:**

For the worst-case for algorithm would be when the array is sorted. So, for each element (suppose at **i**th index), you will have to compare `i-1` elements.

Therefore, the time complexity = O (1 + 2 + 3 ... + n-1) ~ O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

what you are describing is a kind of "insertion sort", and it is of O(n^2) complexity, since you are comparing O(n) elements to upto O(n) other elements.

as far as sorting goes, disregarding any limitations, the best average case complexity you can get is O(n*logn) which is achievable with Merge-sort.
so it would be better to insert all items to the list, and then sorting.